# How to disconnect edges

Tags: modeling, edges

How do I disconnect edges/vertices?

I would like to disconnect an edge loop, so can I move them individually. (Splitting the mesh into two is not an option.)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- **Dissolve** *Mesh > delete > dissolve* will delete geometry and fill in the surrounding area in a non destructive way
- **Rip** rips apart vertices or edges <kbd>V</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

In *Edit Mode*, select the *Edge Loop*, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to bring up *Edge Specials* menu and choose *Edge Split* operator, which allows to split the geometry along the loop:

[image]

You can get each part into selection by using [Select linked](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#select-linked) menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>).